# How can i remove the laravel-logo in the reset password mail from Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

i am just developing a laravel shop, including a password reset functionality. So far so good, everything works pretty fine and in meantime i have also implemented an "email-blade-file" to customize the the content of the mail-text.

```
@component('mail::message')
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level === 'error')
# @lang('Es tut uns leid!')
@else
# @lang('Guten Tag!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Intro Lines --}}
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
<?php
    switch ($level) {
        case 'success':
        case 'error':
            $color = $level;
            break;
        default:
            $color = 'primary';
    }
?>
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $actionUrl, 'color' => $color])
{{ $actionText }}
@endcomponent
@endisset

{{-- Outro Lines --}}
@foreach ($outroLines as $line)
{{ $line }}

@endforeach

<!-- 
{{-- Salutation --}}
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
@lang('Regards'),<br>
 {{ config('app.name') }} 
@endif


{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($actionText)
@slot('subcopy')
@lang(
    "If you’re having trouble clicking the \":actionText\" button, copy and paste the URL below\n".
    'into your web browser:',
    [
        'actionText' => $actionText,
    ]
) <span class="break-all">[{{ $displayableActionUrl }}]({{ $actionUrl }})</span>
@endslot
@endisset

-->

@endcomponent
```

As you can see, something is commented out, because i do not use all this stuff. Here i can handle something like Greetings, Salutions and so on. In addition to this, i have also implemented a new notofication: ResetPassword:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        
            ->subject('Shucube - Passwort vergessen?')
            ->line('Sie haben Ihr Passwort vergessen? Kein Problem...')
            ->action('Passwort Link', url('/'))
            ->line('Beste Grüße...');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

This also works pretty fine. The main part you can se in the function toMail(). All in all you can say that I handle the main content in ResetPassword.php and the general part in the blade file. Cool stuff.

But until now i am not able to remove the laravel logo which is located on the top of the mail. In best case I want to replace it with my own logo. Does anybody have an idea?

[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ0LG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From shell run `php artisan vendor:publish` and then select Laravel-mail. This will create blade views for mail in resources/views/vendor/mail

Answer (score 0):

If you change your APP_NAME from .env file from "Laravel" to anything else, it will disappear